# Why doesn't open my link?

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have that code for two tabs

```
<li>
  <a href="#gallery_place" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
   <i class="fa fa-picture-o"></i>
   <?php _e("Gallery", ET_DOMAIN); ?>
  </a>
</li>
<li>
  <a href="http://romanianusa.com/post-place?id=<?php the_ID(); ?>">
    <i class="fa fa-history"></i>
    <?php _e("Repost", ET_DOMAIN); ?>
  </a>
</li>
```

Why of the second `<li>` does not open, Chrome display my link in bottom but when i click doesn't open the page. What is wrong?

Comment: Can you show the html output?

Comment: Can you show the function `the_ID`? Does it echo the ID or return it?

Comment: onclick of link, can you see console error...check that and post it here....

Comment: I don't clearly understand what is happenning because of the absence of the_ID() function. But you may try like this <?php echo the_ID(); ?>

Answer (score 4):

If the function `the_ID()` returns the ID, you need to use `echo` to get the ID into the URL:

```
<a href="http://romanianusa.com/post-place?id=<?php echo the_ID(); ?>">
```

Comment: Yes, put my ID, but when i click on my Text "Repost" doesn't open my page

Comment: Do you have a Javascript click handler that's overriding the default behavior? You tagged the question with jQuery, is there `$("a").click()` code?

Comment: Yes, i have jQuery, but here i want a sample link

Comment: you need to change the jQuery selector so it only matches the links that you want to process specially, not all the links.

Comment: Thanks, i use that: function openWindow()
 {
  window.open('http://romanianusa.com/post-place?id=<?php the_ID(); ?>');
    }
</script> and in my href i put onClick function. Thanks

Comment: From the last comment, it seems that yet again you aren't echoing out the value for this id. You could try using `<?=` instead of `<?php echo` if you don't fancy typing out long stuff.

Comment: @MoraruVladut Why didn't you write that in the question?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved with that function:

```
    <script>
function openWindow()
    {
        window.open('http://romanianusa.com/post-place?id=<?php the_ID(); ?>');
    }
</script>
```

And in my `<li>`

```
<i class="fa fa-history" onclick="openWindow()"></i><?php _e("Repost", ET_DOMAIN); ?>
```

Thanks a lot @Barmar